# Delete contents of textbox on pause/resume

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an app that allows users to call a phone number from a textbox and a button. As you already know, phone numbers are very private. When the user doesn't kill the app but just presses the home button the phone number of the previous user stays there. What I want the onPause method to do is have the phone number deleted from the textbox on the onPause/onResume method. It seems very simple in practice but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's a rather simple procedure:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id);
    tv.setText("");

    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    textBox.setText("");
}
```

Assuming your text box is an EditText or a TextView this code will do what you need.